# Filtering On Multiple Search Criteria With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, input

I have a problem with my searching in JavaScript / jQuery. For example, if I choose "Two service" and "Online status" this function below returns **all** "Two service" **and all** "Online service".

The desired behavior has 3 parts:

1) For the different search criteria to be **additive** (i.e. ANDs instead of ORs).

2) Return all records when the search criteria is empty.

3) Make the `data-name` search from the `#search` input **case insensitive**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#service").change(function(){ select(); });
  $("#search").keyup(function(){ select(); });
  $("#status").change(function(){ select(); });

  select = function(){
    var service = $("#service").val();
    var search = $("#search").val();
    var status = $("#status").val();

    $(".box").hide();

    $(".box[data-service='" + service + "']").show();
    $(".box[data-search='" + search + "']").show();
    $(".box[data-status='" + status + "']").show();

  }

});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/L7wyp13q/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#service").change(function() {
      select();
    });
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
      select();
    });
    $("#status").change(function() {
      select();
    });

    select = function() {
      var service = $("#service").val();
      var search = $("#search").val();
      var status = $("#status").val();

      $(".box").hide();
      var boxes = $(".box").filter(function(index) {

        return (service === 'all' || $(this).attr("data-service") === service) &&
          (!search || $(this).attr("data-name").toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ) &&
          (status === 'all' || $(this).attr("data-status") === status);
      });
      console.log(boxes);
      boxes.show();

    }

  });
```

fiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/xcrmyzgr/2/

Comment: Your example, I really like. Select "service" and "status" work very well. The problem is still in the "search". For example, in the input write a value of "bc" or "BC" - return is empty. In my view, the result should be: AbCdE (4x) and BcDeF (4x).

Comment: @Tinware See my solution, I think it's everything you're looking for

Comment: @Tinware you could also take another look on my answer, please

Comment: @Quentin Roger There is problem, whose I can't understand. Look: "a" return empty, "A" return empty, "b" return only "AbCdE" without "BcDeF", "B" return "AbCdE" without "BcDeF"

Comment: @Tinware: please tell us what browser are you using? my example works on all browsers(even IE 8 is no problem) and the search bar was really searching at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to build your selector dynamically based on the values of your filter criteria. I used an object to contain the filter values so that I could iterate over them and reuse the property names, but you can do it however you'd like.

#### Edit -- updated to return partial matches from search field, rather than only exact matches

#### Edit 2 -- added case insensitive searching

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#service, #status").change(function(){ select(); });
  $("#search").keyup(function(){ select(); });

  select = function(){
    var selectorFilters = {
      service: $("#service").val(),
      status: $("#status").val()
    };

    $(".box").hide();

    var selector = Object.keys(selectorFilters).reduce(function (sel, currentKey) {
      var value = selectorFilters[currentKey];
      if (value && value !== "" && value !== "all") {
        sel += "[data-" + currentKey + "=" + value + "]"; 
      }
      return sel;
    }, ".box"); // <-- start with .box and build from there

    // will select even if search is partial match, rather than only exact match
    $(selector).filter(function (){
      var searchValue = $("#search").val().toLowerCase();
      return (searchValue === "" || $(this).data("name").toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1);
    }).show();
  }
});
```

#### [Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbr6xj0q/3/)